# « Étudier » or « apprendre » le français

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

> J’ai commencé à **apprendre** le français quand j’avais dix ans.

or

> J’ai commencé à **étudier** le français quand j’avais dix ans.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, are there any differences?

Comment: It's just the difference between "learn" and "study". You can learn something without studying it. For example, if someone teaches you it all orally outside of any formal instruction setting, I'm not sure I would call that *étudier*. Also, *appendre* can mean "teach" with an indirect object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *immortels* in the *Académie Française* do not cease to *étudier* the French language while they only used to *apprendre* it when they were kids.

Comment: There must be some low level _apprentissage_ still going on even with the _immortels_, though the core of their knowledge is indeed well established. :p

Answer (score 3):

They could both be correct but *apprendre le français* is learning French and *étudier le français* is studying French.
In this sentence the meaning of studying is more in an academic way.

Answer (score 3):

Both are quite technically right.  But 'apprendre' is more common, 'j'etudie l'allemand' has a stuck-up whiff about it..

Comment: I agree. Use "apprendre", if you use "etudier" it'll sound like a bad translation from "study".